Bug with htaccess redirection
I have a problem with two redirects that are in the same domain.
If I click on a (redirected) link from the original page, it adds parameters to the url and crashes the site.
Is it my simple redirection that is not correct?
Redirect permanent /fr/pages/8-ever-l/ /fr/artists/1-everl-l/
Redirect permanent /fr/pages/9-arnaud-bissot/ /fr/artists/2-arnaud-bissot/

If I click, I have language settings after the slash (?strLangue=fr)
Best Regards

And what does "crashes the site" actually mean?

Since there is no mentioning of such a parameter strLanguage in those two rules you can safely conclude that they are not the issue here. Most likely it is your application logic resposible for that. Use your browser's development console, the networking tab in there to analyze the redirection headers you receive for your requests.

You probably have an internal rewrite configured, that translates the URL language prefix into this GET parameter - and it interferes with these redirects as well somehow. Show us your full rewrite & redirect setup, please.

there is indeed a part of the rewrite which includes this parameter and it passes if I do a page redirection
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(strLanguage)+
